# My .appxupload is too small

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I just finished developing a project on Windows 8.1 using C#. My project files size is 220 MB.
Now I want to upload my project to the store. I generated the .appxupload file but it's size is only 4.9 MB. Is that normal? I feel like it is too small

Comment: Do not fear my young padawan. I am in posesion of project with weight of 1.16 GB with resulting binary consuming only 1.2 MB of disk space. Eh, damn this C++ and its wicked multi-step compilation.

Comment: @PTwr - the question was about C# though?

Comment: What's taking up the 220MB? What's the size of the binaries and assets if you zip them (like is done for the `.appxupload` file)? Most importantly, does the application work?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, so is my project, but it is infected with native components. It is normal for complicated Visual Studio project to reach crazy size, source code is small portion of data in them. Binary for multiple pltaforms for both debug and release, intermediate files, logs, settings, sample files etc. As long as final binary is of normal size there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @WiredPrairie the size of the project when it is zipped is 56.5 MB! Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem here is the definition of "the size of my project".

Comment: I mean the size of my Visual Studio Project that contains my classes and images.

Comment: Clean build of just release for binaries? No extra fluff in the directories (and no source control "hidden" directories)? And it's 56MB? That would be a bit strange.

Comment: @WiredPrairie yea that's what I was thinking too.So I uploaded it to the Store yesterday and went going through the testing phase and they opened it successfully. There are just some bits here and there that they told me to change.